# How To Select The Files With Same Name In Two Folders

Tags: 16.04

Let's guess I have two folders: A & B.

Now, there are 600+ files in folder A and 400+ files in folder B.

There are many files which share the same name in these two folders.

I.E. file.so in folder A and file.so in folder B.

Now, there are also some files which are not present in both of the folders, I want to ignore them.

So, is there any software that can do this without much hassle?

Comment: Oh, I see now, the files are named the same in both folders. Update you question to make this really clear, it will help you get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: NVM guys, got it: rsync --existing /path/to/dirA/* /path/to/dirB/

Comment: @MarkKirby apologies, I'll delete my comment.

Comment: @TanujSingh Fell free to post an answer to your own questin, it may help others too.

Comment: @MarkKirby Done :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do it:

```
rsync --existing /path/to/dirA/* /path/to/dirB/
```

It'll update the files from dirA to dirB.

Credit: Impavidus @UbuntuForums

Comment: +1 for the effort :) Most don't bother.